# Display a calendar in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, calendar

I am searching a lot from last 2 days regarding this. Any help given will be really appreciable. I wish to display a  neat yearly calendar on my website. After it is displayed, i need to get the dates from mysql database and reflect them on the calendar. For now , i am not able to get anything to display the calendar. Can anybody help me providing a way towards any library or code or anything that might help me for this. I dont need a google calendar. Please suggest me something. I have no idea of doing this.

Comment: Please help me displaying a calendar. M not getting anything for now

Comment: What do you think about jquery calendars? Eg.: http://www.vissit.com/jquery-event-calendar-plugin-english-version

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_calendar

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Sir i dont need a date picker. I just want to display a calendar.

Comment: I have worked with get_calendar and date picker, but i dont need either of them. Is there a library or code that displays me a calendar and get me the dates from mysql

Comment: @david sir .. thank you, i am going through these plugins. But can u guide me for one thing, i need the calendar only for one page, so how should i use the plugin

Comment: I do not know wordpres well, but I think you can add this plugin to yout page and create a helper function that fills it with data. You can call that function only where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try any plugin to display the calander/events . here is some

https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar

https://wordpress.org/plugins/spider-event-calendar/screenshots/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-calendar/screenshots/

Comment: sir-Thanx for the help. But,I dont need to add an event calendar but a calendar to reflect the dates from database with different colors. I have tried all these options. Morever, the calendar appears to a subscriber only so i dont know how to use my calendar plugin to display a calendar only to a subscriber.

Comment: If u can help me with these things, i will be grateful to you

Comment: then you need to create your custom calneder with foreachoop . which contain 12 months and days in every months then you can take an option to choose year . and display in the box whatever you want .